# worpdress: custom design for password protected page if custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, password-protection, custom-fields

is there a way to create a custom password page design (by injecting html/css), if the wordpress post/page contains a specific "custom field" match? see basic logic below..

```
(if post/page is password protected) && (if post/page contains customfield == "designme") 
{
echo "html and css here";
}
```

I found these two pages that might help:

https://themeskills.com/how-to-password-protect-wordpress-page-post/

https://wpsites.net/web-design/add-custom-class-to-style-password-protected-posts/

Comment: 1. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219773/conditional-to-test-if-post-has-password-protection-enabled

Comment: 2. simple meta check using 'get_post_meta' and 'is_set'.

Comment: That should get you on track, but shout if you need more help.